# Changing file browser in Scientific Linux

Tags: gui, scientific-linux

I use Scientific Linux Release 6.1 (Carbon) with GNOME 2.28.2.
When I double-click on a folder on the Desktop it is opened in "File Browser".
When I open a folder via "Places" on the Main Menu Bar, the folder is opened in "File Manager".
I dislike "File Manager" and I don't understand why there are two different programs (file managers) running depending on how I open a folder.
How can I get rid of "File Manager"?

Answer (score 2):

If Nautilus (your file manager) is just a box (spatial view) go to "edit", then select "preferences" and in "behaviour" choose "Always open in browser windows".
Then close the window and open it again.